Manually specifying x-axis limits with gglikert()
I am using the gglikert() function from the ggstats package to create horizontal stacked bar charts centered on the neutral response. I would like to know how to manually set the x-axis limits to 100% on either side of 0%. Here is an example dataframe and code (please ignore factor ordering being incorrect!):
example_data <- data.frame(
            Pre = as.factor(c("Somewhat Familiar","Unfamiliar","Somewhat Familiar",
                              "Somewhat Unfamiliar","Somewhat Familiar","Unfamiliar",
                              "Neither Unfamiliar or Familiar","Unfamiliar",
                              "Neither Unfamiliar or Familiar","Unfamiliar")),
           Post = as.factor(c("Very Familiar",
                              "Very Familiar","Somewhat Familiar",
                              "Very Familiar","Very Familiar","Very Familiar",
                              "Very Familiar","Somewhat Familiar","Very Familiar",
                              "Somewhat Familiar"))
   )


gglikert(example_data,
         add_totals = FALSE)

Likert Plot
Here, you can see that the function has set the axis limits based on the percentages within each of the groups. I would like the x-axis to go to 100% (as there are other questions with different data distributions and I would like all the axes to be the same, though the answers are slightly different, so I can't facet them).
I have looked at the documentation for gglikert() and searched Google/Stack overflow, and I do not see an option for the axis limits.
I've tried setting the limits with typical ggplot2 approaches (e.g., xlim(0, 100) or xlim (-100, 100)), but because the x-axis isn't on a typical sequential scale like from -100 to 100, these approaches haven't worked.
I've opted for this approach rather than the likert package as it has better functionality for the downstream formatting I want to apply (more control over faceting, facet labels, and bar labels), so would prefer solutions that use gglikert().

Replace the existing continuous x scale with a new one that has limits c(-1, 1) and then apply percent label formatting from the {scales} package.
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstats)
library(scales)

example_data <- data.frame(
            Pre = as.factor(c("Somewhat Familiar","Unfamiliar","Somewhat Familiar",
                              "Somewhat Unfamiliar","Somewhat Familiar","Unfamiliar",
                              "Neither Unfamiliar or Familiar","Unfamiliar",
                              "Neither Unfamiliar or Familiar","Unfamiliar")),
           Post = as.factor(c("Very Familiar",
                              "Very Familiar","Somewhat Familiar",
                              "Very Familiar","Very Familiar","Very Familiar",
                              "Very Familiar","Somewhat Familiar","Very Familiar",
                              "Somewhat Familiar"))
   )

gglikert(example_data, add_totals = FALSE) + 
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = label_percent(), 
    limits = c(-1, 1)
  )
#> Scale for x is already present.
#> Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.


Created on 2024-07-03 with reprex v2.1.0.9000
Reprex files hosted with  on GitHub

Thank you so much, this worked!! I changed it to scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) abs(x)*100, limits = c(-1, 1)) so that the values are positive (I don't care too much about the "%" part of the label, since I'll just add an x-axis title).
